# How to define properties with a handwritten getter/setter in managed C++?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, syntax, properties

I need to define properties with handwritten getters/setters in a managed C++ project, in a class that will be usable from a C# .NET project.

- The [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1050/Using-properties-in-managed-C) on the subject recommends the `__property float Volume;` which is outdated and now classified as `/crl:oldSyntax`.
- The [Open Standard managed extensions to C++ article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1600.html) says that defining properties like `property float Volume;` automatically generate a backing field, which I don't want or need.
- Simply defining properties like `property float Volume;` compiles fine with `/clr`, but attempting to add handwritten getters/setters like `float Mixer::Volume::get(){ .. }` throw `Error C2084: function X already has a body`.

So what is the proper way to define read-only or read/write properties without a backing field, and with custom-built handwritten getter/setter methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found you have to declare the property only ONCE in the header file, as follows:

```
property float Volume {
    float get() {
        return 0;
    }
    void set(float value) {
    }
}
```

If you declare the property like the follows, a backing field is automatically generated:

```
property float Volume;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have found the header-only version by yourself. If you want to implement the getters and setters in a cpp file, the syntax is as follows:

```
///////////////////////
// Foo.h:
///////////////////////
ref struct Foo
{ 
    property float Volume
    {
        float get();
        private: void set(float value);
    }
private:
    float m_backingField;
}

///////////////////////
// Foo.cpp:
///////////////////////
float Foo::Volume::get()
{
    return m_backingField;
}

void Foo::Volume::set(float value)
{
    m_backingField = value;
}
```

**Edit: Some additional information**:

- You can specify different access modifiers for the getter and the setter. I modified the source code in order to make the setter private. **Note that unlike in C# this is not possible if you use the automatic generation of backing store.**
- What was called "managed extensions for C++" earlier, is now (starting with Visual Studio 2005) called C++/CLI. It is not only a renaming but a complete new revision. The double underscore `__property` keyword came from the managed extensions and is now deprecated.

Comment: There is no need to use `private:` if you don't want to provide set-property. Just don't implement `set` ~

Comment: @Ajay: You are right. There are situations where no setter is needed (imagine `DateTime.Now` had a setter). But when the property is used with a backing store, as in the example, I would implement the setter.